# Testing multicast traffic load in unidirectional network

Tags: networking, stress-test

I have the following Ethernet network connection:

```
Client PC --> The Box --> Server PC
```

The box is a system which passes only multicast UDP traffic and only in one direction.
I need to create a test which checks the traffic load and integrity of the data received by the server PC.

I tried iperf3 but it has a TCP handshake before starting the UDP flow.

I tried iperf2 but it cannot send multicasts.

I tried nping but it only sends packets and I need to manually check the link performance in Wireshark.

So I'm looking to a tool with multicast client and server which will check the packets and report speed, loss, jitter, broken data.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a TFTP server such as Solarwinds? (which uses UDP port 69) You can run a fully UDP server and simply use the built in client on the other side to make a file request